# Finding Hamiltonian path in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have weighted, undirected full graph (generated from points in R^2), where weight between every two vertices are euclidean distance between corresponding pair of points.

What I'm trying to do is find shortest hamiltonian path in this graph - however **not** hamiltonian cycle.

Is there any clever way to do it in *Mathematica*? Or maybe not so clever, but still simple?

Edit: example

```
graphMatrix = {{0, 0.140892, 0.298153, 0.466667, 0.640739, 0.81446, 0.982061, 
1.13827, 1.27866, 1.4}, {0.140892, 0, 0.167897, 0.3564, 0.558216, 
0.765518, 0.970331, 1.16492, 1.3422, 1.49614}, {0.298153, 0.167897, 
0, 0.198762, 0.420358, 0.655838, 0.895711, 1.13035, 1.35045, 
1.54743}, {0.466667, 0.3564, 0.198762, 0, 0.231951, 0.487784, 
0.757188, 1.02926, 1.29299, 1.53768}, {0.640739, 0.558216, 0.420358,
0.231951, 0, 0.266598, 0.557422, 0.86095, 1.16502, 
1.45736}, {0.81446, 0.765518, 0.655838, 0.487784, 0.266598, 0, 
0.302202, 0.628537, 0.966347, 1.3023}, {0.982061, 0.970331, 
0.895711, 0.757188, 0.557422, 0.302202, 0, 0.338461, 0.70068, 
1.0729}, {1.13827, 1.16492, 1.13035, 1.02926, 0.86095, 0.628537, 
0.338461, 0, 0.375184, 0.773562}, {1.27866, 1.3422, 1.35045, 
1.29299, 1.16502, 0.966347, 0.70068, 0.375184, 0, 0.412249}, {1.4, 
1.49614, 1.54743, 1.53768, 1.45736, 1.3023, 1.0729, 0.773562, 
0.412249, 0}}
graph = Graph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[graphMatrix], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: weighted graph]

And in this case hamiltonian path would be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}` (or equivalently `{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10}`).

```
HighlightGraph[graph, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10}]
```

[image: hamiltonian path in graph]

Comment: If it is allowed to return an approximation of the shortest then you could try `FindShortestTour` and remove the longest leg of the tour it returns.

Comment: I thought about this - and if it isn't other way I will use it.

However I'm wondering if there's any better way.

Comment: Would you please add a test case and the output you would expect?

Comment: @Öskå I've added a test case - I hope it's more clear now!

Comment: @Öskå thank you for editing - I'm new to this particular stack exchange :)

Comment: No worries, your post was quite well edited already :)

Comment: I do not know of a straightforward better approach, though others might. If the number of points is modest, say up to several dozen, then 0-1 integer programming methods might be viable. That would take several lines of code to set up constraints for `FindMinimum`. Not outrageous though, if your needs fit the capabilities of this approach (must give near-optimal result and not too many points).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Daniel Lichtblau suggested, Using FindShortestTour might be the best way.

For example,

```
shortestPath[g_] :=
 Block[{tour, pos},
  tour = UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[FindShortestTour[g][[2]], 2, 1];
  pos = Last[Ordering[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ tour]];
  Rest[RotateLeft[tour, pos - 1]]
 ]
```

I replace 0 to Infinity to remove loops (doesn't really matter for computing though).

```
mat = graphMatrix /. {0 -> Infinity};
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mat, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
path = shortestPath[g]
```

> {10 <-> 9, 9 <-> 8, 8 <-> 7, 7 <-> 6, 6 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 4 <-> 3,   3
>   <-> 2, 2 <-> 1}

```
HighlightGraph[g, path]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In versions 10.2+, you can use [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html):

- **"`HamiltonianPath[g]` finds a Hamiltonian path in the graph `g` with the smallest total length."**

```
hpath = FindHamiltonianPath[graph]
```

> ```
> {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[graph, PathGraph @ hpath, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]